# How to group array of dates to periods startdate-enddate? If one weekday is missing between dates then new period begins in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

```
20.01.2017
23.01.2017
24.01.2017
25.01.2017
26.01.2017
27.01.2017
31.01.2017
01.02.2017
```

Lets say i have these dates. All those dates are workdays. 
Output should be

```
20.01.2017-27.01.2017
and
31.01.2017-01.02.2017
```

Since 30 January is workday and so the first period is not continiuing and new period starts.

What is the best way to approach this.

I was thinking taking first date in array and putting it into a new array. Then comparing next date in array to the previous one if it's next day (ignoring weekends). If it is not nextday then take previous date and put it to array as end date and then start a new array of next period.

Comment: Key to solution: [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

You can get the date in milliseconds and sort

Comment: This does not make any sense. How would that help with my problem?

Comment: [Date.getDay()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) returns you the day of the week for a given date. Maybe that can help you...

Comment: @Smiranin—absolutely not. Do not use *Date.parse* (or the Date constructor) to parse strings.

Answer (score 0):

Get your first date (I'm supossing you have them ordered, as in your example data they are) and store it on a variable for the start date.

Store the same value also in another variable for the end date.

Now loop through your dates checking if current looped date is the next one after your current end date. If it's, store your current looped date into the end date variable and continue to the next loop. If it isn't return current start and end dates and store your currently looped date as a new period start date, go on until loop ends and return current variables.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach, though not the shortest or maybe best way of facing this. Just take it as an idea

```
var array = [
    "20.01.2017",
    "23.01.2017",
    "24.01.2017",
    "25.01.2017",
    "26.01.2017",
    "27.01.2017",
    "31.01.2017",
    "01.02.2017"
];

var isNextDay = function(day, nextDay) {
    var day1 = new Date(day.slice(3, 6) + day.slice(0, 3) + day.slice(6)); //had to format the date this way to make a valid date
    day1.setDate(day1.getDate() + 1); //sets the next day, nextday of 30 or 31(last day of month) is 1
    var day2 = new Date(nextDay.slice(3, 6) + nextDay.slice(0, 3) + nextDay.slice(6));
    if (day1.getTime() === day2.getTime()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

var dateGroup = function(dateStrings) {
    var res = [];
    var aux = dateStrings[0] + "-";
    for (var i = 1; i < dateStrings.length; i++) {
        if (!isNextDay(dateStrings[i - 1], dateStrings[i])) {
            aux += dateStrings[i - 1];
            res.push(aux);
            aux = dateStrings[i] + "-";
        }
   }
    aux += dateStrings[dateStrings.length - 1];
    res.push(aux); //this is because the last one never gets pushed
    return res;
}

var output = dateGroup(array);
```

Comment: You can't rely on `new Date(nextDay.slice(3, 6) + nextDay.slice(0, 3) + nextDay.slice(6))`. Parsing random strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse) is notoriously inconsistent across implementations.

Comment: of course, this is an implementation that strictly needs 2 things, the date formats to be that way and the array of dates to be sorted, I just had to use it cause my nodejs would understand mm.dd.yyyy with that date format

Comment: Not sure if "*would*" should be "*would not*". But in any case, it highlights that you should not use the *Date* constructor or *Date.parse* for parsing. Once you've parsed the string into tokens, you're much better off to use those values directly with the constructor than making a new string and going back to `new Date(string)` or the *Date.parse* equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the dates and calculate what the string for the next date should look like, then compare to see if it's the same. If not, end the previous period and start a new one.

You can use a library to parse and format the dates, but simple functions to do the job are just a couple of lines, e.g.

```js
var dates = ['20.01.2017','23.01.2017','24.01.2017',
             '25.01.2017','26.01.2017','27.01.2017',
             '31.01.2017','01.02.2017'];

/* Parse date in format D/M/YYYY
** @param {string} s - date to parse lke 23.1.2017
** @returns {Date}
*/
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], b[1]-1, b[0]);
}

/* Format a date in DD/MM/YYYY with supplied separator
** @param {Date} date - date to format
** @param {string} s - separator, default is /
** @returns {string} date formatted as DD/MM/YYYY with supplied separator
*/
function formatDMY(date, s) {
  s = s || '/';
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
  return [z(date.getDate()),z(date.getMonth()+1),
          date.getFullYear()].join(s); 
}

/* Create array of date ranges in DD.MM.YYYY-DD.MM.YYYY format
** @param {Array} data - array of date strings in DD.MM.YYYY format
** @returns {Array} array of range strings in DD.MM.YYYY-DD.MM.YYYY format
*/
function createRanges(data) {
  var result = [];
  var previous;
  data.forEach(function(s, i) {
    var previous, previousNext, current, range;
    // If on first loop, create a range using first value
    if (i == 0) {
      result.push(s + '-' + s);
     
    // Otherwise, get end date of last range and add one day
    } else {
      previous = result[result.length-1].split('-')[1];
      previousNext = parseDMY(previous);
      previousNext.setDate(previousNext.getDate() + 1);
      previousNext = formatDMY(previousNext,'.');
      
      // If current date is same as previousNext, update range. 
      // Otherwise, start a new range
      if (s == previousNext) {
        range = result[result.length-1];
        result[result.length-1] = range.split('-')[0] + '-' + s;

      } else {
        result.push(s + '-' + s);
      }
    }
  });
  // Remove zero day ranges. Could do this by checking last range
  // when creating a new one but seems simpler to do it here
  result = result.filter(s=>!(s.split('-')[0] == s.split('-')[1]));
  return result;
}

console.log(createRanges(dates));
```

However, a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) will help with parsing, formatting and arithmetic.

Comment: Yes but what about the weekends.

Comment: The OP said "*ignoring weekends*", so I did. ;-) It would not be hard to stop the range on Fridays and start again on Mondays. What are "weekends"? Not everyone uses Saturday and Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Same as made by Leandro, but made for an array with Date objects and with using moment.js

```
function groupDates(dates) {
    const res = [];
    const isNextDay = (day, nextDay) => moment(day).add(1, 'day').isSame(nextDay, 'day');
    const format = "DD.MM.YYYY";

    let aux = moment(dates[0]).format(format) + "-";
    for (let i = 1; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if (!isNextDay(dates[i - 1], dates[i])) {
            aux += moment(dates[i - 1]).format(format);
            res.push(aux);
            aux = moment(dates[i]).format(format) + "-";
        }
    }
    aux += moment(dates[dates.length - 1]).format(format);
    res.push(aux);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution with Luxon lib

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

const test = [
    "2022-06-23",
    "2022-06-24",
    "2022-06-25",
    "2022-06-26",
    "2022-06-27",
    "2022-06-28",
    "2022-06-29",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-03",
    "2022-05-05",
    "2022-05-04",
    "2022-05-06",
    "2022-05-07",
    "2022-05-08",
];

function getRanges(datesArr) {
    const periods = [];
    let ix = 0;
    const dates = datesArr.map((d) => DateTime.fromSQL(d));
    dates.sort();
    dates.forEach((date, index) => {
        if (index === 0) {
            periods.push([
                date,
            ]);
        } else if (date.diff(dates[index - 1], [ 'days' ]).days === 1) {
            periods[ix].push(date);
        } else {
            ix += 1;
            periods.push([ date ]);
        }
    })
    return periods;
}

console.log(getRanges(test));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.4.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can get first and last elements from each ranges